# Setting tab title colors on JTabbedPanes

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

On a JTabbedPane, how do you set the color of the tab titles for both the selected and unselected states?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like what you want are the `setForegroundAt` and `setBackgroundAt` methods in `JTabbedPane`.

Comment: You're half-right.  setForegroundAt does set the color of the tab title for both the selected *and* unselected states.  setBackgroundAt sets the tab color itself and has no effect on the tab title color.  Anyway, I'm hoping I don't have to use one of the "At" methods.  I want to change the colors for all of them and let Swing handle knowing which tab is currently selected.

Comment: +1, manual control is more reliable then depending on the LAF to do this for you.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to change the colors for all of them and let Swing handle knowing which tab is currently selected.

That wouuld be a LAF implementation. You can check out [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/). For the Metal LAF it looks like background selected/unselected can be controlled but I don't see anything for the foreground font color.

So I would say you would need to add a ChangeListener to the tabbed pane. Then you can manually reset the selected background/foreground using the methods provided by Kainsin.