# How to change the color of the JTabbedPane tabheader?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jtabbedpane, uimanager

We got a homework where we should code a table program. I am trying to make a small excel program. My question is how to change the color of the JTabbedHeader. Here a picture so you can see what part I mean.[The red highlited part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4uaP.png)

I have found out which component has to be colorized so you can change the "header"-Color of the JTabbedPane. It is just the color of the Component, where the JTabbedPane is on. So in my code it is the contentPane.

Comment: Show your code what you done

Comment: Is changing the color of the header part of the homework? If so, the teacher is an idiot and you should find a better one. If not, your extra time would be better spent double, then triple checking the code works, or documenting it, or ensuring it follows good MVC principles or.. (insert a dozen more code things here). Changing header colors is the programming equivalent of futzing.

Comment: No it is not part of the homework. We do not even have to make a menu with JTabbedPanel. But in my opinion it is the most fancy method to create a menu. What do you mean with futzing? Do you mean fuzzing?

Comment: @Sambit that could be hard cause it is much code in a mvc model. With diffrent Methods (i wrote) to create it.

Comment: Check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6767668/setting-tab-title-colors-on-jtabbedpanes

Comment: Also check complete example. https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/jtabbedpane/set-tab-color-in-jtabbedpane/

Comment: @Sambit both of your links show how to change the color of the tab. But tha is not my problem. I Want to change the color of the background. So that thing which is behind the tabs. You can see it on the picture.

Comment: *"What do you mean with futzing?"* GIYF. BTW - Tip: Add @Sambit (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson i used @ didnt I?

Comment: @KaNaDa, first try to write a simple standalone code for jtabbedpane and try to add background color. If it does not work, you can share the code in stackoverflow so that people can help you.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thank you for your help i have found the problem. I just used a code where you can see all the Components your hole JFrame has and changed every color for it self so I can see which Pane I have to color. I have found out that it was the most simple one. The "header" color of the JTappedPane is the color of the JPane where it is on. In my code it is the ContentPane